# Reassigning a pointer func parameter

Tags: function, pointers, go

I'm trying to reassign a pointer to a new value that's been passed on as func parameter, but once I step out of the function, the pointer has a nil value again.

I've stepped through the code and it seems to work until I step out of the function into the calling function where the passed on pointer still holds a NIL value.

```
func Prepare(db *sqlx.DB, stmt *sqlx.Stmt, query String) error {
    res,err := db.PreparexStatement(context.Background(), query)
    stmt = res
    return err
}
```

I would expect the following to work:

```
func Boot(db *sqlx.DB, stmt *sqlx.Stmt, query String) {
    err := Prepare(db, stmt, query)
    if err != nil {
        //handle
    }
}
```

I'm still fairly new to GO, so I believe I fail to grasp a concept here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters act as local variables inside a function. You may change their values, but that only changes the values of the local variables. They are independent from the variables whose value you pass.

If you want to modify something, you have to pass its address, and modify the *pointed* value, e.g.:

```
func main() {
    var x int
    fmt.Println("before", x)
    set(&x)
    fmt.Println("after", x)
}

func set(i *int) {
    *i = 2
}
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TSJ-_Z4YPm1)):

```
before 0
after 2
```

The same thing applies to pointer variables: if you want to modify a pointer variable, you again have to pass its address, and modify the pointed value. In case of a pointer, the type will be a pointer to pointer, e.g.:

```
func main() {
    var x *int
    x = new(int)
    fmt.Println("before", x, *x)
    set(&x)
    fmt.Println("after", x, *x)
}

func set(i **int) {
    p := new(int)
    *p = 2
    *i = p
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Eo2QVTj75bl)):

```
before 0x416020 0
after 0x416040 2
```

Of course if you have a pointer variable and don't want to modify the pointer value just the pointed value, you can just pass the pointer, and modify the pointed value:

```
func main() {
    var x *int
    x = new(int)
    fmt.Println("before", x, *x)
    set(x)
    fmt.Println("after", x, *x)
}

func set(i *int) {
    *i = 2
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dJDd3DaPxb4)):

```
before 0x416020 0
after 0x416020 2
```

One thing to note: you can't pass a `nil` pointer to a function and expect to be able to assign anything to the pointed value: `nil` pointers point to nowhere. You have to pass a non-`nil` pointer, or as an alternative you may return the pointer value (and assign it at the caller).

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, I assumed pointers would  automatically passed by reference. 

I'm trying to use `*stmt = *res` now and I'm getting a bad memory address, but I assume this error is to be looked for somewhere else?

Comment: @P.Winz I'd assume so. But I don't even know which packages you're using.

Comment: Primarily `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`. What I don't really understand is: I pass an empty `sqlx.Stmt` pointer to this func. I want the pointer to be populated and not actually create a new one. `db.PreparexStatement()` will return another `sqlx.Stmt` pointer, so I should be able to set the value like this `*stmt = res`, right?

I have checked the result of the `PreparexStatement` function and it seems to return a perfectly fine pointer to a perfectly fine struct.

Comment: @P.Winz You can't pass a `nil` pointer and expect to assign anything to the pointed value: `nil` pointers point to nowhere. To be able to set the pointed value inside the function, you have to pass a non-`nil` pointer. Or you have to return the pointer.

Comment: I literally just realized this while doing some research. Thank you for your quick help, I think I grasped the concept now :)